# Optimising iterative loop

Tags: python, matlab, loops, numpy, iteration

I'm gradually moving from Matlab to Python and would like to get some advice on optimising an iterative loop.
This is how I am currently running the loop, and for info I've included the code that defines the variables.

```
nh = 2000 
h = np.array(range(nh))
nt = 10000 
wmin = 1 
wmax = 10
hw = np.array(wmin + (wmax-wmin)*invlogit(randn(1,nh))); 
sl = np.array(zeros((nh,1))+radians(40))
fa = np.array(zeros((nh,1))+radians(35))
c = np.array(zeros((nh,1))+4.4)
y = np.array(zeros((nh,1))+17.6)
yw = np.array(zeros((nh,1))+9.81)
ir = 0.028
m = np.array(zeros((nh,nt)));
m[:,49] = 0.1
z = np.array(zeros((nh,nt)))
z[:,0] = 0+(3.0773-0)*rand(nh,1).T
reset = np.array(zeros((nh,nt)))
fs = np.array(zeros((nh,nt)))

for t in xrange(0, nt-1):
    fs[:,t] = (c.T+(y.T-m[:,t]*yw.T)*z[:,t]*(np.cos(sl.T)**2)*np.tan(fa.T))/(y.T*z[:,t]*np.sin(sl.T)*np.cos(sl.T))
    reset[fs[:,t]<=1,t+1] = 1;
    z[fs[:,t]<=1,t+1] = 0;
    z[fs[:,t]>1,t+1] = z[fs[:,t]>1,t]+(ir/hw[0,fs[:,t]>1]).T
```

This is how I would optimise the code in Matlab, however it runs fairly slowly in python. I suspect there is a more pythonic way of doing this and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.
Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a way for you to pinpoint which of the 4 operations in the loop is taking the most time?  That might help us determine where the most help is needed (I might guess it is the first... trig functions are pretty slow).

Comment: I also notice that you are indexing your arrays in a way that is more optimal for Fortran-storage than C-storage.  You might consider having numpy store your arrays in Fortran-order.

Comment: Thanks Seth, Fortran order sped things up a bit. For info/example this can be done using z = np.zeros((nh,nt), order='F')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specifically about the loop, you're doing a ton of extra work in calls that look like:

```
np.array(zeros((nh,nt)))
```

Just use:

```
np.zeros((nh,nt))
```

in its place. Additionally, you could replace:

```
h = np.array(range(nh))
```

with:

```
h = np.arange(nh)
```

Other comments:

- You're calling `np.sin(sl.T)*np.cos(sl.T)` in every loop although, `sl` does not appear to be changing at all. Just calculate it once and assign it to a variable that you use in the loop. You do this in a bunch of your trig calls.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I've assigned the trigs before the loop now and tidied up the array definitions. Slight improvement in speed and looks a lot tidier. Cheers

Comment: It would also be worth your while to look at the documentation on broadcasting rules in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(c.T+(y.T-m[:,t]*yw.T)*z[:,t]*(np.cos(sl.T)**2)*np.tan(fa.T))/(y.T*z[:,t]*np.sin(sl.T)*np.cos(sl.T))
```

uses `c, y, m, yw, sl, fa` that do not change inside the loop. You could compute several subexpressions before the loop.

Also, most of those arrays contain one repeated value. You could compute with scalars instead:

```
sl = radians(40)
fa = radians(35)
c = 4.4
y = 17.6
yw = 9.81
```

Then, with precomputed subexpressions:

```
A = cos(sl)**2 * tan(fa) * (y - m*yw)
B = y*sin(sl)*cos(sl)

for t in xrange(0, nt-1):
    fs[:,t] = (c + A[:,t]*z[:,t]) / (B*z[:,t])
    less = fs[:,t]<=1
    more = np.logical_not(less)
    reset[less,t+1] = 1
    z[less,t+1] = 0
    z[more,t+1] = z[more,t]+(ir/hw[0,more]).T
```